# How to turn on font features with Libertine and LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'd like to get the Libertine fonts with the font features `hlig`, `liga` and `onum`, and also load the relevant mono font and Biolinum for the sans font.

It seems I can simply use `\usepackage{libertine}` to get the font with LuaTeX according to the [Libertine documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf), but having read that plus the [fontspec documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), I'm not able to figure out how to actually turn on these features. Something to do with `Ligatures=Common`, `Ligatures=Historic`, etc. but where do I put these?

Comment: Did you try (a) loading the `fontspec` package and (b) issuing the instruction `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}, Numbers=OldStyle]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? (to be compiled under LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX)

[image]

Speaking for myself, I find `Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}, Numbers=OldStyle` easier to read than `RawFeature=+liga;+dlig;+hlig;+onum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}%
   [Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}, Numbers=OldStyle]
\begin{document}
0123456789

ff fi fj fl ft ffi ffl fft, tt, ct st

\itshape
ff fi fj fl ft ffi ffl fft, tt, ct st
\end{document}
```

Comment: To add the associated sans-serif font, you could run `\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}[Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}, Numbers=OldStyle]` after `\setmainfont`. Not sure which mono font you consider to be the "relevant" one.

Comment: Hmm, I think because I know the raw feature names, `RawFeature` makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Mico It works well for me for the serif/italic font, but regarding the comment for the sans-serif font: I just tried it (switched to Biolinum or Libertinus Sans with `\setsansfont` and `\sffamily`), and only the `ff`, `ft`, `tt`, `ct` and `st` ligatures show up. `fi`, `fj`, `fl`, and `Th` do not. Do you know if this is a (lacking) feature of the fonts or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Faekynn - I don't think you're doing anything wrong: Both Linux Biolinum O and Libertinus Sans feature far fewer ligatures than their Serif counterparts do. I'm not an expert in font design; that said, it is my impression that sans-serif fonts generally make do with fewer ligatures. This may be because of their lack of serifs.

Answer (score 6):

From page 3 of the `libertine` package manual:

> The option `defaultfeatures=...` allows the user to add default OpenType features.

You can therefore do this in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[defaultfeatures={Ligatures={Common, Historic, TeX}}
           ]{libertine}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

[image: Test]

You can also use another package, such as `libertine-otf`, with a `Ligatures=` package option.  Or bypass the package entirely and use `fontspec`.